Unit test mocked data can return only one time. after that it returns null
I am unit testing method which interact with SolidEdge api. Solid Edge API is a COM components used to automate 3D model changes like AutoCAD.
Mocked data can return only one time. after that it returns null.
All mocking are working fine but it only works on first call. Because of that, I got value "Yes" from includeIn1 but null value from includeIn2. Even though both access same property.
public static ResultModel GetMockedAssemblyDocument(MockRequestModel mockRequestModel)
{
    var mockAssemblyDocument = new Mock<AssemblyDocument>();
    var mockOccurrences = new Mock<Occurrences>();
    var mockOccurrenceList = new List<Mock<Occurrence>>();

    foreach (var occurrence in mockRequestModel.OccurrencesDetails)
    {
        var mockOccurrence = MockSolidEdgeDocumentOccurrence(occurrence.OccurrenceName, occurrence.Properties, occurrence.Variables);
        mockOccurrenceList.Add(mockOccurrence);
    }

    mockOccurrences.Setup(o => o.GetEnumerator()).Returns(mockOccurrenceList.Select(mock => mock.Object).GetEnumerator());
    mockAssemblyDocument.Setup(doc => doc.Occurrences).Returns(mockOccurrences.Object);

    return new ResultModel { MockedAssemblyDocument = mockAssemblyDocument, MockedAssemblyDocumentCount = 2 };
}

public static Mock<Occurrence> MockSolidEdgeDocumentOccurrence(string occurrenceName, Dictionary<string, object> properties,
    Dictionary<string, VariableInfo> variables)
{
   // Existing code
    mockOccurrence1.SetupGet(o => o.OccurrenceDocument).Returns(() =>
    {
        var mockSolidEdgeDocument = new Mock<SolidEdgeDocument>();

        var mockPropertySets = GetPropertySetsMock(properties);
        mockSolidEdgeDocument.Setup(doc => doc.Properties).Returns(mockPropertySets.Object);

        return mockSolidEdgeDocument.Object;
    });

    return mockOccurrence1;
}

private static Mock<PropertySets> GetPropertySetsMock(Dictionary<string, object> properties)
{
    var mockPropertySets = new Mock<PropertySets>();
    var mockPropertySet = new Mock<Properties>();

    var propertyObjectType = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        dynamic dynamicProperty = new ExpandoObject();
        dynamicProperty.Name = property.Key;
        dynamicProperty.Value = property.Value;

        propertyObjectType.Add(dynamicProperty);
    }
    mockPropertySet.Setup(ps => ps.GetEnumerator()).Returns(propertyObjectType.GetEnumerator());
    mockPropertySets.Setup(ps => ps.GetEnumerator()).Returns(new List<Properties> { mockPropertySet.Object }.GetEnumerator());

    return mockPropertySets;
}

[Test]
public void GetSupportData_ShouldReturnListOfComponents()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockRequestModel = new MockRequestModel
    {
        OccurrencesDetails = new List<MockOccurrenceRequestModel>
        {
            new()
            {
                OccurrenceName = "Occurrence1",                  
                Properties = new  Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { nameof(FilePropertyNameConstants.ObjectType), nameof(ObjectTypeConstants.Elbow) },
                    { nameof(FilePropertyNameConstants.IncludeIn), "Yes" }
                }
            }
            
        }
    };

    var mockAssemblyDocument = GetMockedAssemblyDocument(mockRequestModel);
    _mockConnectionRepository.Setup(repo => repo.GetAssemblyDocument()).Returns(mockAssemblyDocument.MockedAssemblyDocument.Object);

    // Act
    var result = _isometricRepository.GetData();

    // Assert
    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);      
}

public List<ResultModel> GetData()
{
    // Existing code 
    
        SolidEdgeDocument occurrenceDocument = occurrence.OccurrenceDocument;

        if (!occurrenceDocument.PropertyValueExists(FilePropertyNameConstants.IncludeIn, out object? includeIn1)) continue;
        if (!occurrenceDocument.PropertyValueExists(FilePropertyNameConstants.IncludeIn, out object? includeIn2)) continue;

        // Existing code 
    
}


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

There's a lot of code in that post. Please edit and reduce it to a minimal, reproducible example. Assume that we don't know what SolidEdge is.

We don't really see the relation with COM here. Plesae make it visible or remove the tag. Don't know how you create your COM objects and use them, might be a multi-threaded or a threading issue.

Every time a mock returns a mock, somewhere a child's kitten turns into an insect. https://www.instagram.com/reelsonwheels/p/CvQfchEL_0J/?img_index=2

My following existing setup directly assigns the result of propertyObjectType.GetEnumerator() to be returned whenever GetEnumerator() is called on the mock object. This means the same enumerator instance is returned each time.
mockPropertySet.Setup(ps => ps.GetEnumerator()).Returns(propertyObjectType.GetEnumerator());
mockPropertySets.Setup(ps => ps.GetEnumerator()).Returns(new List<Properties> { mockPropertySet.Object }.GetEnumerator());

Solution is to setup using a lambda expression to return the enumerator. Each time GetEnumerator() is called on the mock object, a new enumerator is created.
mockPropertySet.Setup(ps => ps.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => propertyObjectType.GetEnumerator());        
mockPropertySets.Setup(ps => ps.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => new List<Properties> { mockPropertySet.Object }.GetEnumerator());

